# Pyspark error occurred while calling o50.load. : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: pyspark

I need help am struggling with pyspark jdbc error on my jupyter notebook..im connecting to a database url from local to somewhere else my code is as of below

1. installed sql connector
   2.installed mysql workbench to test out the connection
2. installed jupyter and did the set up,
   Im honestly not sure what lib or installs im missing do i need to download a local mysql server?

```
   import findspark
    findspark.init
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    sqlContext = sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    
    #connection to oc_customer_reward (find store credits customers gain), change db and port 
    
    df_storecredit = sqlContext.read     \
        .format("jdbc")     \
        .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://link")     \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")     \
        .option("dbtable", "(SELECT customer_id, order_id, date_added as 'timestamp', points from oc_customer_reward) as orders")     \
        .option("user", "")     \
        .option("password", "")     \
        .load()
    df_storecredit.printSchema()
    
    
    #add project_id column
    
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
    
    df_projectid = df_storecredit.withColumn('project_id', lit(''))
    df_projectid.printSchema()
    
    #Save the dataframe to the table. 
    db_properties = {"user": "","password": "","driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
    df_projectid.write.jdbc(url='jdbc:postgresql://link',table='dwh_storecredits',mode='append',properties=db_properties)
```